# Adding elements to different collections in a single lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I possibly use the wrong terms, feel free to correct.

I have a test method which takes a `Runnable`:

```
void expectRollback(Runnable r) { .. }
```

I can call this method like this:

```
expectRollback(() -> aList.add(x))
```

Cool, I understand lambdas! This is awesome. Let's be super clever...

```
expectRollback(() -> aList.add(x) && bList.add(y))
```

But what? That doesn't compile: `'void' methods cannot return a value.` Doesn't the first call also return a value though? What is the difference between the first and the second call?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [mcve]. It should be easy for you to write one - it's easy for everyone else too, but it's better for *one* person to do it (you) than everyone who wants to help.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou: But `List.add(E)` returns `boolean`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's subtle, but I think I've got it.

In [JLS 15.27.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) we have:

> A lambda expression is *congruent* with a function type if all of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - If the lambda parameters are assumed to have the same types as the function type's parameter types, then:
>
>   - If the function type's result is `void`, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.
>   - ...
> - ...

Now `aList.add(x)` is a statement expression, but `aList.add(x) && bList.add(y)` is not. You can see that without any lambdas involved - just try to use them as statements:

```
aList.add(x); // Fine
aList.add(x) && bList.add(y); // Error: "not a statement"
```

If you wrap that expression in a method call, it's fine, because the method call is a statement expression again:

```
rollback(() -> Boolean.valueOf(aList.add(x) && bList.add(y)));
```

I'm not actually suggesting you do that - just trying to explain why that would work but your previous attempt didn't.

If we assume that `List.add` really will return `true` every time as documented, just use a block lambda:

```
rollback(() -> { aList.add(x); bList.add(y); });
```

I'd argue that's clearer anyway as it makes it more obvious that you *don't* care about the value returned by the first `add` call.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. I'll rather just create a new void helper method, still better than an anonymous class. I'll try to make a complete example next time.

Comment: @JonSkeet exactly - this is called the special void compatibility rule

Comment: Or just put it in a block. I though I had tried that previously but no.. () -> { a.add(x); b.add(y); }

Comment: @zedoo: Will add that into the answer now.

Comment: A new `=>` operator?

Answer (score 5):

Basically your first expression is way to invoke a method but ignore the result:

```
 aList.add(x) // actually returns a boolean but you ignore this result
```

This is not anything new for lambdas actually, as it has been like this since java appeared:

```
List<Integer> list ...
list.add(1); // returns boolean but we ignore the result almost always
```

So why is the result not ignored in your second example? Well because the `JLS` says so, as seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8). There are 4 types that will work though:

```
Method Invocations
Assignments
Increment and Decrement expressions
Class Instance Creation expressions
```

Your last example uses `&&` which is neither of the 4 types described in the JLS, thus a compile time error.

You could create a `helper` method to add to both lists(or as you did with `Boolean.valueOf`):

```
public static boolean helper(int x) {
    boolean result = first.add(x) && second.add(x);
    return result;
}
```

And use it:

```
expectRollback(() -> helper(x))
```

Comment: Or just use a block lambda with an if statement, of course.

Comment: Ha, but I'm actually not even interested in the conditional add. (Apart, list.add is true by definition..) I just want to execute both adds. Still, Jon had the right hint, 'void compatible block'. Just use a block!